# How to trigger an automatic screen lock process on my android phone after a specified process running specified time?

Tags: android, android-intent, lockscreen

I want to control my android smartphone that after my son playing games on my phone after a specified time such as half an hour, the phone will be locked unless you submit the right password.

I don't know how to trigger the lock screen process.

How can I implement interrupting the games processes and lock the cellphone?

Answer (score 0):

[How unlock and lock screen programatically in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7648347/how-unlock-and-lock-screen-programatically-in-android) Has some excellent information on immediately calling the lock screen. You could implement a system using an alarm manager to trigger this event.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good example,

first thing you need to do this, U need to know when the screen gets unlock. So here you go.....

[android-detect-phone-unlock-event-screen-on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446202/android-detect-phone-unlock-event-not-screen-on)

After that you set a time for 30/40/50 minutes (as you wish). 
Once the timer fires, use below link to lock your screen.

[lock-phone-screen-programmtically](http://rdcworld-android.blogspot.in/2012/03/lock-phone-screen-programmtically.html)

And your work is done.